# Is there any pyspark function or substitute for like in sql

Tags: pyspark

I have a python list of all the columns of the dataframe as below.

```
['Timestamp',
 'ScheduleCode__VALUE',
 'ScheduleCode__i:nil',
 'ProductionCode__VALUE',
 'ProductionCode__i:nil',
 'ProductCode__VALUE',
 'ProductCode__i:nil',
 'ProductCategory__VALUE',
 'ProductCategory__i:nil']
```

I need to drop all the columns from the above list which ends with __i:nil and rename all the columns with __value to only it's prefix like ProductCode__VALUE should be renamed to ProductCode.

Comment: Do you have some pyspark code written? If so, could you also paste that?

Comment: Do you want this in pyspark dataframe or pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
column_list = ['Timestamp',
 'ScheduleCode__VALUE',
 'ScheduleCode__i:nil',
 'ProductionCode__VALUE',
 'ProductionCode__i:nil',
 'ProductCode__VALUE',
 'ProductCode__i:nil',
 'ProductCategory__VALUE',
 'ProductCategory__i:nil']

for element in column_list:
    if(element.endswith('__Value')):
        df = (
            df.withColumnRenamed(element, element.split('__')[0])
        )
df = df.drop(*[element for element in column_list if element.endswith('__i:nil')])
```